# ForEach Loop (C#) Missing Out First Item

Tags: c#, wcf, foreach

I have a WCF Service which includes a foreach loop:

```
foreach (var fileName in questionnaireRequest.StoreItem.Files)
{
   //// Processing done here
}
```

This works fine when run locally, and each of the items in the collection is processed.

However, on the server, the first item in the collection is always skipped.

A real puzzle.

The only difference I can see is that we are running .Net version 4.5.2 locally, the server is running version 4.5.1.

Has anybody seen this type of behaviour?

Comment: No. You will need to do some debugging.

Comment: Certainly, this is not an issue of .NET version. I would suggest you debug your code and compare `questionnaireRequest.StoreItem.Files` in both your server and your local PC. The `foreach` can't skip items. It consumes (iterating forward only), the items in a collection that provides an enumerator.

Comment: What is the type of `Files`? How have you validated that it's being skipped rather than not being present in the collection to start with?

Comment: Could you post code how questionnaireRequest.StoreItem.Files getting initialized/modified prior to foreach loop?

Comment: You need to debug the service and check the contents of the list - it isn't missing the first item. Either your evidence is wrong or the item you expect isn't there - foreach doesn't behave any different on the server.

Comment: Is there a debugger available? If not, can you dump something into a file or the Windows event log?

Answer (score 0):

We finally found the solution - there is a load balancer involved in this solution, so the files could be stored in one of two servers, determined by the load balancer.  In this case, sometimes the files were being stored on one server, but the next call to the web service ran on the second server.

Two possible solutions - enable sticky sessions on the load balancer, or have a shared folder for files accessible by both servers.